# item click listener for ListView having ResourceCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursor

How to provide a  onItemClickListene to ListView when ResourceCursorAdapter is used

I have a class which extends ListActivity

I have tried so many things like

1) Implementing `OnItemSelectedListener` and overriding `onItemSelected` by setting      `getListView().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

But this approach fails as the above would work for Adapters i guess not for ResourceCursorAdapter.

2) I tried adding only `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener)` but that doesn't call too.

3) I tried overriding  onListItemClick(l, v, position, id) too , but that doesn't get call too.

Now i really don't know how can i make a listview clickable for ResourceCursorAdapter